# How do Ruby and Python implement their interactive consoles?

Tags: python, ruby, interpreter, command-line-interface, interactive

When implementing the interpreter for my programming language I first thought of a simple console window which allows the user to enter some code which is then executed as a standalone program as a shell.

But there are severe problems: If every line of code the user enters is handled as a standalone program, it has to go through the tokenizer and parser and is then just executed by the interpreter - what about functions then?

- How can the Python/Ruby interactive consoles (IDLE, irb) "share" the code? How is the code entered handled?

Example:

```
>> def x:
>>  print("Blah")
>> 
>> x()
```

Where is the function stored so it can be called at any time again?

**How can the interactive console take everything entered as obviously one program without executing everything over and over again?**

Answer (score 4):

For Python, an expression isn't complete until all parentheses, brackets, etc. match up. This is fairly easy to detect. A function/class definition isn't complete until a completely blank line is entered. The compiler then compiles the entered expression or definition, and runs it.

Much like a normal function, class, module, etc., the REPL has its own local scope. It's this scope that is used for variables and definitions entered into the REPL.

Answer (score 3):

You can learn more about the Python interactive console by reading the documentation for the code module:

> The code module provides facilities to implement read-eval-print loops in Python. Two classes and convenience functions are included which can be used to build applications which provide an interactive interpreter prompt.

http://docs.python.org/library/code.html

Answer (score 3):

Most of these languages use a parser which has a kind of "token stream" -- that is, the parser keeps taking tokens (a string, symbol, operator, etc) from the input stream until it has a full expression, then it returns that parsed expression where it might be compiled to bytecode or otherwise executed.  A REPL loop is relatively simple to handle given that structure, as the parser basically asks for more input, and you give the user a prompt and have the user enter more input.  You might need a bit of communication from the parser to the reader to make it render things like continuation prompts.

Python and Ruby both execute statements immediately, in-order (a function declaration is one statement).  So you can execute code statement-by-statement at the interpreter to largely the same effect as in a source file.